# Mutating a variable based on whether other multiple columns are all NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a column and set it to 1 based on whether all particular columns (with similar name pattern) is NA.
This is what I have tried so far and doesn't seem to work.
Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
mutate(
    column_to_create = 
        case_when(
            is.na(vars(matches('pattern'))) ~ as.character(1)
    )
)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(column_to_create = as.integer(rowSums(!is.na(select(., 
                                       matches('pattern')))) == 0))
```

This should give 1 when all the values in the column that has `'pattern'` in them has `NA` and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This unfortunately doesn't seem to work. Every value in column_to_create is output as 1. If multiple NA's are 'rowSummed', then does that = 0?

Comment: Wouldn't using 'select' retrieve all the rows of the dataframe? not just the row that we are in currently?